# Mapplet parameter not taking value from Paramter file (Informatica)

Tags: parameters, mapping, informatica

I've added a parameter in my mapplet and I'm passing the value through a parameter file which is being called by the workflow. It reads from the file and at workflow level it stores the correct value. But it gets replaced by 'default value' as null at mapping level and hence the session fails when this null is passed in an expression.

I want to pass 55000 as the value, not null.
Following is the session log:-

```
VAR_27028    Use override value [55000] for user-defined workflow/worklet variable:[$$func_num].

VAR_27027   Use default value [] for mapping parameter:[mplt_test1.$$func_num].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that I had not named the parameter correctly in the parameter file. 
Earlier it was 
    $$parameter_name=55000
but it should have been 
    mapplet_name.$$parameter_name=55000
It works now!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I used the parameter in my mapping instead of mapplet. After this you can use that value as the input to mapplet and use it in your mapplet.

Comment: definitely passing a parameter via parameter file to a mapplet works... issue most likely in how you are naming the variable in your parameter file i.e. can you share the section where you set your parameter in your parameter file and we'll advise fix

Comment: @DanielMachet I tried couple of things. First I tried to declare a variable at mapplet and using the parameter at workflow level but it didnt worked out. After that i tried to pass the variable at workflow level and then assigning it to the mapplet variable using pre session variable assignment.

Comment: @DanielMachet true! The name was issue for me.

Comment: @PragyaVashishtha The name as in variable name? Can you give an example as how name was an issue.

Comment: @prashantsugara please check the solution I just posted for this. Right on top of your answer. :)

Comment: No problem - glad to hear its sorted now